# MySQL full text search ranking

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I found in this [article](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_Algorithms#Full-text_Search) the formula that MySQL use to ranking in FTS

> w = (log(dtf)+1)/sumdtf * U/(1+0.0115*U) * log((N-nf)/nf)

Where

> dtf     is the number of times the term appears in the document sumdtf
> is the sum of (log(dtf)+1)'s for all terms in the same document U
> is the number of Unique terms in the document N       is the total
> number of documents nf      is the number of documents that contain
> the term

But I wonder that what is **0.0115**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your source:

> The normalization factor is the middle part of the formula. The idea
>   of normalization is: if a document is shorter than average length then
>   weight goes up, if it's average length then weight stays the same, if
>   it's longer than average length then weight goes down. We're using a
>   pivoted unique normalization factor. For the theory and justification,
>   see the paper "Pivoted Document Length Normalization" by Amit Singhal
>   and Chris Buckley and Mandar Mitra ACM SIGIR'96, 21-29, 1996:
>   http://ir.iit.edu/~dagr/cs529/files/handouts/singhal96pivoted.pdf. The
>   word "unique" here means that our measure of document length is based
>   on the unique terms in the document. We chose 0.0115 as the pivot
>   value, it's PIVOT_VAL in the MySQL source code header file
>   myisam/ftdefs.h

So, it's a "best practice" pivot value.